# What is your recommended approach for testing website every 5 minutes for one hour per day

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an android app that checks a website every 5 minutes for one hour a day, weekdays only, and I am not sure what the best mechanism for scheduling it is.  JobScheduler is nice, but only available in Android 5.0 or better which won't do.  A SyncAdapter might work, but I normally keep master sync off (and this will be a personal app for me).  Right now I am thinking alarms will work, but I wondered if anyone had any other advice.

FYI, the app is intended to run with WiFi network while charging in the wee early morning hours to alert me if the website has an alert posted.

Comment: Check out the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class.

Comment: Thanks drschultz, I think that is where I am headed.  Do you think that is the best approach?  Any others I should look into?

Comment: See my answer below. Please accept it if you feel it provides the information you were looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class should do exactly what it is you want it to do. You could have the device wake itself up at, for example, 3am on Saturdays and Sundays, run for an hour and be sending network requests every 5 min, and then shut off when finished.

Some sample code ([taken from the Google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set)) shows an example of how to set an alarm that will trigger at 3am, then continue firing every 5 minutes after that. You'll probably need some extra logic to get the exact control you want (e.g. weekends only, etc) but this will give you an idea of how to get started...

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 3:00am
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 5 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 5, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Sweet.  Thank you for the example code.